# Putting an object first in an Eloquent Collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I got a model.

```
$items = Item::all();
```

I am doing a `foreach loop` in the `HTML`, and I'd rather have certain object first.

I am currently converting the `$items->toArray()`, searching the name of the item and putting it first.

Is there any way to do this in `Eloquent`?

Comment: You can prepend an item to the start of a collection:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-prepend is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @user10341554 I looked into that, but since I am extracting data from DB and not adding anything, I won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$sorted = $items->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->name == "Name" ? 0 : 1;
});
```

This will put the item you want first, first. I don't know for sure if it will affect the rest of the order, but I don't believe it will.

Answer (score 1):

try doing this

```
$items = Item::all();

$items = $items->sortBy(function($item){
   return $item->name == 'name';
});
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby